# getAs(MimeType.PDF) or getAs('application/pdf') with spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Has getAs(MimeType.PDF) or getAs('application/pdf') functionality been changed recently?

A sample of my code:

```
var blSheet = DriveApp.getFileById('templateID').makeCopy(title, destFolder);
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.open(blSheet);
var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
sheet2.getRange("B9").setValue(valueHere);
sheet2.getRange("C10").setValue(valueHere);
sheet2.getRange("D11").setValue(valueHere);
sheet2.getRange("B9:B11").merge();
sheet2.getRange("C9:C11").merge();
```

etc...

Then adding this spreadsheet to an email using

```
blSheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
```

This worked fine up until a week ago. Now the attached pdf in my email is the blank template. When I look at the new spreadsheet in my google drive, it has the appropriately updated/merged cells.

Any help?

It seems to me that either getAs is taking the spreadsheet before it's cells are updated/merged, or it is taking the first "version" of the spreadsheet even after it's been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) for `sendMail()`'s attachments option. It requires a [BlobSource[]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) object array. It actually just accepts a Google Drive File without modification and attaches it as a PDF -- no extra work required.

Just give MailApp sendMail a File object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you might be experiencing is that the changes made to the sheet are not fully committed.

You might need to call:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
```

That will commit your changes to the drive file and hopefully solve the issue.